# Where does `lsp-mode` keep session state?

Tags: lsp-mode

When opening source code files for the first time, `lsp-mode` asks whether to "import" the project or not. It looks like it saves the project information somewhere - where can I find that file and is there a way to set it? Are there any other files that are saved (apart from the language server's (e.g. `gopls`) files which must be specific to the language server.

Here I'm assuming that a "session" is the list of projects known to `lsp-mode`.

Answer (score 1):

The path is given by the variable `lsp-session-file` which is defined in the file `lsp-mode.el`. The docstring says "File where session information is stored.", and the default value is `(expand-file-name (locate-user-emacs-file ".lsp-session-v1"))`.

Comment: I can report that when `.lsp-session-v1` got overcrowded, my lsp-related commands became slow and on big projects they'd time out. After running `lsp-workspace-folders-remove-all`, things started working again.